# How to install istio in private network without access to internet?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I install istio in private network, that have no access to internet.

I can pull images from public repositories as kubernetes.io, docker.io etc and push it in out private docker registry, then use it for deployments.

But i cannot find how to specify this our private docker registry in istioctl?

When i do

istioctl install --set profile=demo -you

I see Err Image Pull Back Off:

Warning  Failed          56s (x2 over 76s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/is to/pilot:1.13.3": rpc error: code = Unknown disc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

How to tell istioctl to pull images from our private docker registry?
And how to get list of images for copy it in our registry?